# How do I loop through an arrayList to store them as different objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, data-structures

I have an Arraylist of String.

```
private List<String> listGroup = new ArrayList<String>();
```

One elements of listGroup is
`"CyberHacking Tools,CLS,Tim Hemmingway,2,P132303,Tyler Johnson,APP,M,P132304,Patty Henderson,APP,F"`.

I need to store the first five elements into a project object which has constructor in project class, while looping the rest to store them into Student object with constructors in Student class. The student object only holds 4 parameters and after every four, it will store a new student object. All of these objects will hence be passed into a Student and Project list.

The codes for these objects are written below.

In the Project class:

```
    public Project(int noOfProj, String title, String sch, String superv, int NoOfStudent) {
        this.noOfProj = noOfProj;
        this.title = title;
        this.school = sch;
        this.supervisorName = superv;
        this.noOfStudent = NoOfStudent;
        // this.projIndex = projCode;
    }
```

This is the Project object:

```
Project p = new Project(title, school, supervisorName, noOfStudents);
```

I have a project class, student class,FileReader class and JFrame class respectively. What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are creating new Student object after four parameter as you mentioned in you problem "The student object only holds 4 parameters and after every four, it will store a new student object."

Comment: Do you mean that the whole `"CyberHacking Tools,CLS,..."` is one of the strings in `listGroup`, or each of the comma-separated string is an element in the list?

Comment: Will there always be a correct number of elements? Can there be like 12 elements, where the last 3 cannot form a student object?

Comment: What is the `noOfProject` parameter?

Comment: @Sweeper I think `2` is the value for parameter `noOfProject` and value for `NoOfStudent` parameter is not present in the input. we need to calculate the number of students by parsing the input string as I've shown in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you want to store the project and student objects for later usage. Here's the approach you can take:

```
List<Project> personList = new ArrayList<Project>(); //store list of projects
List<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<Student>(); //store list of students

for (String str : listGroup) 
{
    String arr[] = str.split(",");

    // as student object takes 4 arguments and "noOfStudents" is 
    // the number of "Student" objects found in the string
    int noOfStudents = (arr.length / 4)-1;

    Project p = new Project(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]), arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], noOfStudents);
    personList.add(p);

    for (int i = 4; i < arr.length-4; i += 4)
    {
        listStudent.add(new Student(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2], arr[i+3]));
    }
}
```

**Note:** while creating the objects of `Person` and `Student` I've passed parameters arbitrarily assuming the sequence of the `string`s will be consistent. Hope you can pass the parameters according to your constructor parameter sequence.

Comment: I am certain that you dont need to calculate the noOfStudents.

Comment: @ajc reason...? I've used because of constructor: `public Project(int noOfProj,String title, String sch, String superv, 
intNoOfStudent)`

Comment: If you look at the input, `CyberHacking Tools,CLS,Tim Hemmingway,2` Logically, the last parameter should ideally be the noOfStudents

Comment: @ajc That is because of `noOfProj` parameter

Comment: This is just my perspective - but I dont see any mapping between input and the noOfProj parameter. The Op has to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your `Project` constructor seems to have `4` parameters and not `5`. Said that,

```
    // considering this as your sample line -
    // String line = "CyberHacking Tools,CLS,Tim Hemmingway,2,P132303,Tyler Johnson,APP,M,P132304,Patty Henderson,APP,F"

    String[] tuple = line.split(",");

    // Get first 4 tuples for Project. 
    // CyberHacking Tools,CLS,Tim Hemmingway,2
    Project project = new Project(tuple[0], tuple[1], tuple[2], tuple[3]);

    // Iterate over rest of the tuples for Student. 
    // P132303,Tyler Johnson,APP,M 
    // P132304,Patty Henderson,APP,F
    for (int i = 4; i < tuple.length; i += 4) {
        Student student = new Student(tuple[i], tuple[i + 1], tuple[i + 2], tuple[i + 3]);
        // add the student object to List<Student> here. 
    }
```

Comment: According to your assumption `new Project(tuple[0], tuple[1], tuple[2], tuple[3]);` should show undefined constructor. Because your last parameter should be `int`.

Comment: Yes, this is not a working code. This is a guideline to solve the problem.